# The server returned the HTTP status code 406 + how to obtain stocks data

Tags: data, finance, url

Any solution for this:

```
Import["https://es.investing.com/indices/germany-30-futures-\
historical-data"]
```

not successful. The server returned the HTTP status code 406. Options `"Data"` or `"JSON"` does not work

Any idea how to obtain the data of this webpage?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be that the site in question has (pretty basic) defence against bots, and does not let you download it programmatically for a default type of request that `Import` is making.

You can set HTTP headers to pretend that you send a request from a browser, to overcome this:

```
url = "https://es.investing.com/indices/germany-30-futures-historical-data";

response = URLRead @ Append[
  URLParse[url],
  "Headers" -> {
    "User-Agent" -> 
      "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"
  }
]

(* HTTPResponse[Status: OKContent type: text/html;charset=UTF-8] *)
```

Now you can access the contents of HTML page as `response["Body"]`. For example:

```
ImportString[response["Body"], "XMLObject"]
```

Comment: Not work for me, The answer is:  General::erropts: The value None specified for the option Username is invalid.  How to include an username?  the username contains "@"

Comment: @roble_t Not sure why this failed for you. The code I posted worked for me, without the need to specify `Username`. I am on  Mac OS X, Mathematica version 11.1.1. What platform are you on, and what Mathematica version you use?

Comment: Also works on 12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020).

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Thanks for confirming. I made a typo. I meant also 12.1.1.

Comment: my username contains an email, xxx@yyy.com. How can I write this in mathematica Username=???. Thanks again

Comment: @roble_t It is not clear to me why you need to provide a username. The site does not require authentication, since the code above works for me without any username. It looks rather like a bug in the Mathematica version you use, which seems unhappy with the setting `"Username" -> None` in the request. Try replacing this: `URLRead @ Append[...]` in the above code with this: `URLRead @ DeleteCases[None]@Append[...]`, and see if that helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer but in windows Mathematica version 11.the result is is:

General::erropts: The value None specified for the option Username is invalid.

Failure[
  "ConnectionFailure", 
  Association[
   "URL" -> "https://es.investing.com/indices/germany-30-futures-historical-data", 
   "MessageTemplate" -> "Unable to perform the request.", 
Mathematica version 11.01.1

Comment: @roble_t Did you actually try my suggestion from the previous comment and include `DeleteCases[None]` in the above code? You seem to come back with the same issue that that suggestion should've fixed.

Comment: yes I have tried the following:  url = "https://es.investing.com/indices/germany-30-futures-historical-\
data";

response = 
 URLRead@DeleteCases[None]@
   Append[URLParse[url], 
    "Headers" -> {"User-Agent" -> 
       "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, \
like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"}] but does not work for me

Comment: @roble_t I don't have version 11 on my machine, so can't test. I would think this is a problem of version 11, since this same code works for me just fine. In other words, I believe that this code solves your original problem, but then you encountered a different one, which is specific to version 11. I don't think I can help with this further, alas.

Comment: For readers: It works for version 12.2 not for verion 11. Thanks Leonid

Comment: @roble_t Glad that it worked for you at the end.